# Expected behavior or a bug of python's dataclasses?

Tags: python

```py
from dataclasses import field, dataclass

custom_field = field()

@dataclass
class A:
    x: int
    y: int = custom_field
    z: int = custom_field

A(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

After executing the following code I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1314913987c2> in <module>
----> 1 A(x=1, y=2, z=3)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

I can overcome this issue by using the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import field, dataclass

custom_field = lambda: field()

@dataclass
class A:
    x: int
    y: int = custom_field()
    z: int = custom_field()

A(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

Tested with python 3.7.9

Comment: By calling `field()` eagerly like you are doing in `custom_field = field()` you are creating only one `Field` object - which is bound to both `y` & `z`. I suspect that is causing dataclasses to misbehave - the created class only has a `z`, no `y`. Instead you should use it how it's documented. You might find the `default_factory` argument to `field` useful.

Comment: Try to `print(*dataclasses.fields(A), sep='\n')` in both cases and see the differences

Comment: It's arguably a bug, as it's possible to detect if an instance of `Field` is being rebound to a second class attribute. I don't know if there is a subtle reason to *allow* that, or if you could safely raise an error if someone attempts to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) creates and returns a single instance of `dataclasses.Field`.

When you do `custom_field = field()` - you simply assign that one `Field` to `custom_field`. Then when you do `y = custom_field`, and `z = custom_field`, you are assigning *the same object* to different names. What ends up happening is that since they are both references to the same field, only the one assigned last, `z`, is kept.

Which is why if you do

```py
A(x=1, z=3)
```

it works just fine
But if you do-

```py
A(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

It raises an exception since `y` doesn't actually exist in the class.

Comment: If you look at the source code, `Field.__set_name__` is used to attach *a* name to each instance of `Field`; this is the point where the dataclass "forgets" about the name `y` if you assign the same object to the name `z`.

Comment: Arguably, this *could* be considered a bug, as `__set_name__` could detect if the same object is being assigned a second time and raise some appropriate error.

Comment: @chepner hmm I see. Also yes, raising an exception when multiple names are being assigned to the same reference would probably be a good idea.